# Difference in project file icons in Visual Studios Solution Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What do the two project icons mean? At a guess it seems the 1st is a C# project and the 2nd is some sort of web project. I can't spot anything in the actual files that would identify the differences.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one is Class Library while second one is Web Project.
The difference is mainly in the first line of .csproj

Class Library uses

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Web project uses

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```